# Add inline javascript on Drupal page

Tags: javascript, drupal, drupal-6

I have an inline javascript that I want to add to a module.page.inc.
How I can do that in the simplest way?

```
<script>
$(function() {
$("a[rel][href!='']").overlay({
mask: {
color: '#000',
loadSpeed: 200,
opacity: 0.8
},
effect: 'apple',
onBeforeLoad: function() {
var overlaid = this, overEl = this.getOverlay();
overEl.find(".contentWrap").load(
this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
overEl.appendTo("body");
$(".close", this.getOverlay()).click(function(e){
overlaid.close();
});
}
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  What have you tried so far?  This sounds like a "please do my work for me" instead of a "help me I'm stuck" type of question, which does not typically get a very favorable response on SO

Answer (score 0):

Try using the function:

```
drupal_add_js('jQuery(INSERT YOUR JS HERE, 'inline');
```

You will need to put the inline script either in a variable or directly where I've put that placeholder. Be careful with your quote marks.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this without script tag

drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () { alert("Hello!"); });', 'inline');